# Dictionary of dictionaries to list

Tags: c#

I need to create a list of names that are keys to **dictionary**. As for me it looks totally OK, but i have couple of errors.
Structure must be like

> { paperony => {Tomatoes, 1}, {Carrot,4}, vegetarian => {Tomatoes, 4},
>   {Potatoes, 6}  }

```
List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>> ingredients = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>();
ingredients.Add(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>()
            {
                {
                    "Paperoni", 
                    {
                        {"Tomatoes", 1},
                        {"Carrot", 4}
                    }
                },

                {
                    "Vegetarian",
                    {
                        {"Tomatoes", 4},
                        {"Potatoes", 6}
                    }
                }
            }

        );
```

Comment: Yes, there should be an instance of dictionary that you create `{ "Paperoni", new Dictionary<string, int> { {"Tomatoes", 1 }, ... } }`

Comment: When dealing with nested Dictionaries/generics, I prefer to use type aliases: `using InnerCollection = Dictionary<string, int>;` `using MiddleCollection = Dictionary<string, InnerCollection>;`, `List<MiddleCollection>`; Of coruse In gerenal, I try to avoid nesting. Especially 2 levels deep. | Honestly that looks more like a XML or JSON represnetation of some proper data Structure, then what you would use in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use explicit initialization of Dictionary. For example,

```
ingredients.Add(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>()
            {
                {
                    "Paperoni", 
                    new Dictionary<string, int>{
                        {"Tomatoes", 1},
                        {"Carrot", 4}
                    }
                },

                {
                    "Vegetarian",
                    new Dictionary<string, int>{
                        {"Tomatoes", 4},
                        {"Potatoes", 6}
                    }
                }
            }

        );
```

If you want to avoid usage of explicit initialization , you could use the following approach.

```
ingredients.Add(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>()
            {
                ["Paperoni"] = {
                                ["Tomatoes"]= 1,
                                ["Carrot"]= 4
                                },
                ["Vegetarian"] = 
                                {
                               ["Tomatoes"]= 4,
                               ["Potatoes"]= 6
                                }
            }

        );
```